# How to retrieve number of users from mysql db by using other db as reference?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem. I have 3 tables in mysql DB table1, table2 and table3. Im using PHP to retireve and write all information.

Table1 has list of organisations with IDs I have created for them:

```
Name of ogranisation | Organisation ID
--------------------------------------
org1                 | 123
org2                 | 234
org3                 | 345
```

Table2 has list of services those organisations are using with their IDs and IDs of organisations from table1 that they belong to:

```
Name of service | Service ID | ID of organisation it belongs to
---------------------------------------------------------------
service1        | a1         | 123
service2        | b2         | 123
service3        | c5         | 345
```

Table3 has the list of users with IDs of services they provide from the table2:

```
Name of User | Service ID 
-------------------------
user1        | a1
user2        | a1
user3        | c5
user4        | b2
```

Now I need, using those tables, to get number of users from table3 who provide services to organisations. Like if you look at table2 you can see that org1 with ID(123) is provided with service1 (a1) and service2 (b2) and in table3 you can see that there are 3 users providing services a1(2x) and b2 so there are 3 users providing services to org1.

How do I get that number form DB with PHP.

Please help and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user)) as cnt
FROM `table3` A
INNER JOIN `table2` B ON A.service_id = B.service_id
INNER JOIN `table1` C ON B.organization_id = C.organization_id
AND C.organization_id =123
```

see **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02230/1)**

Comment: Suggested Updated : `SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT userName )`

Comment: SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM `table3` A
INNER JOIN `table2` B ON A.service_id = B.service_id
INNER JOIN `table1` C ON B.organization_id = C.organization_id
AND C.organization_id =123

Works great. THX

Answer (score 0):

To execute SQL use e.g. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

the query looks like

```
SELECT
    u.name
FROM user u
    INNER JOIN service s
        ON u.serviceId = s.serviceId
    INNER JOIN ogranisation o
        ON s.ogranisationId = o.ogranisationId
```